# The heaviest road-legal truck

Tags: civil-engineering, transportation, specifications

The question is what is the heaviest road-legal truck?
I exclude road trains (except for one full trailer in addition to regular load) and special payloads (such as wind turbines, very large transformers, or seacrafts/ships). I am interested in ordinary truck types.

In terms of the type of truck and payload:

1. Heavy Equipment Transporter (HET) semi-trailer (including tank transporter)
2. Mobile crane with 100+ t (small? medium?) or 200+ t lifting capacity (heavy)
3. Concrete mixer truck (weight when empty and fully loaded)
4. Dump truck (including one with an additional full trailer)
5. Tanker truck (they usually carry water or fuel/oil)
6. General semi-trailer

Also, can you specify the usual or common/average and maximal weights (fully loaded) of each truck type on the above list (1-5, for 6 you would probably need to give a range)?

For example, for article 2, mobile crane:
[image: Mobile Crane]

Heavy (200+ t lift capacity) mobile crane Liebherr LTM 1750-9.1 weighs 108 tons in transportation mode (i.e. while traveling and not while deployed). See specs here:
https://www.avi-cranes.co.il/_files/ugd/3bd1d1_2beeaea05bfe430b850bfc6dbffd74f1.pdf

Comment: What about power to weight ratio?

Comment: What is "road legal"? what weight limits? or are you working on max weight per tyre? What about special loads when they get road limit exemptions? and also take responsibility for possible damage to bridges etc

Comment: Haul trucks like the Caterpillar 777 are not road-legal, as they are too big to drive on an ordinary road. So are tracked vehicles and some types of off-road dump trucks. In my questions, I refer to "ordinary" trucks that are allowed to drive on roads and exclude special payloads.

Comment: @SolarMike, I added power/weight ratio as well.

Comment: So what about a Scammel 6*6 towing a fully laden artic trailer combination?

Comment: So which will it be? max power or max power to weight? Do you get the difference?

Comment: Sounds like someone needs to shop around and build a table of the findings. From a physics standpoint, if you bring together all the legality constraints regarding size and specific weight, some info typical of diesel engines, and diesel fuel, you may be able to calculate a theoretical.  Doesn't do much good though for a theoretical most powerful could be something carrying as much fuel as possible, expending it as quickly as possible.

Comment: I think I will go for the absolute power rather than power/weight because many types of trucks, especially the general semi-trailer, can carry different amount of payload and thus pull different weights with the same engine.

Comment: @jsotola So you suggest I split the question into two: heaviest truck type, and powerful truck model?

Comment: Your comments about the Caterpillar 777 get pretty close to why you've asked an unanswerable question.  "Legal" is not a hard and fast term -- it changes over time, it depends on whether you can get special permits, it changes with jurisdiction, it changes with how the laws are interpreted, etc..  Even the question "what can I drive across the United States without special permits" is fraught with argument over what the term "special permit" means, and what combination of states have reciprocal operating agreements vis-a-vis truck and trailer registration.

Comment: I hit "enter" and had an "aha!" moment -- this isn't an engineering question per se.  It's a legal one, and while engineering often dances on the border between applied science and law, in this case I think you want to find a forum full of truckers, and -- better yet -- heavy cargo dispatchers.  **They** will know.  They will have it forcibly ground into their skin, by every oddity in the laws of the places that they need to send cargo through.  If you do ask, be sure to ask what jurisdiction you're talking about (the states, in the US, I really don't know outside of that).

Comment: Well, it is not a mechanical engineering or engineering of a machine, but rather a question about civil engineering and the application of heavy equipment. Regarding "special permit" issue: in my question I asked for the normal heaviest road truck, excluding special payloads, special permits and mega-projects.

Comment: Probably logging trucks. The heaviest scaled was 325,000 pulled on a haul road 20 miles to the sawmill by a Kenworth conventional in California. West Virginia coal wagons are exempt and won't be stopped as long as the coal isn't visible above the sideboards. So figure 120,000 pounds plus.

Comment: Transporter carrying 120 ton excavator. - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1BsUzu2qF4

Comment: So over 923000 lbs and 220 feet long: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZq2Y4dh4hk

Comment: @SolarMike This transformer (~420 t) is probably regarded as a special payload.

Comment: @PhilSweet The HET carrying 120 t excavator is a good contender. Thanks also for linking to the video showing how it is loaded, transported, and unloaded.

Comment: But they are all road legal… as in they are allowed on the road  You should soon add enough exceptions that you will have written the Construction and Use regs.

Comment: Also, road trains are legal (e.g. in Australia) and can pull hundreds of tons in more than 2 full trailers. Therefore I "artificially" excluded them, along with special payloads. Powerful semi-trailers tractors (like Peterbilt 389 with 600 hp engine) can pull special payloads but I explicitly stated that I am interested in "normal" trucks. You can answer that a semi-trailer pulling 200 t payload is the heaviest road truck today.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a "heaviest road-legal truck". There are tons of different kinds of trucks you can analyze when load rating bridges and doing pavement design. Every state has their own list and they are all different, and not all roads and bridges are designed- or rated- to carry every "road legal" truck. And just about any special truck can attempt to obtain permission to legally drive on a road- though it may require an engineer to look at the roads and bridges to check that it's acceptable.

However, in the US, the design live load in the AASHTO LRFD bridge design code (which is the model code used by every state in the US) is known as HL-93 load. This is about as close to what you are asking: the heaviest "road legal" truck- meaning, the kind of truck you can pretty much assume a typical road ought to have been designed to handle, and local jurisdictions won't have a problem with.

This live load consists of checking two conditions:

1. A 36 ton truck load supported by three axles: 8 kips, 32 kips, and 32 kips, on two sets of 10"x20" tire patches (ie, about 80 psi tires). This condition is also known historically as HS-20 load.
2. A 50 kip "tandem" axle spread out to four sets of 10"x20" tire patches (ie, about 62.5 psi tires).

The reason there are two conditions is that, depending on what you are looking at, the worst-case load could be the heavier 50 kip axle spread over 4 patches, or the lighter 32 kip axle spread over 2 patches.

In addition to this standard live load, it is also required to consider the contribution of impact, or dynamic, loading resulting from the vibration/movement of the vehicle. The increase from impact varies depending on what you are looking at, but the maximum is a 33% increase applied to the values above*. Adding this 33% impact would increase the heavy axle load above to about 42.7 kips for the HS-20 truck, and 66.7 kips for the tandem axle.

Below is a diagram of the HL-93 truck (ie, HS-20) design live load. Note that the center-to-center "wheel base" is assumed to be 6 ft.

[image: AASHTO LRFD HL-93 design live load]

Below is a diagram of the HL-93 tandem axle design live load.

[image]

Another very common live load is exactly the same as #1 above, but increased by another 25%. This is known as the HS-25 live load. Instead of the heavy axles being 32 kips, they are 40 kips (and the 10"x20" tire patches come out to be 100 psi).

* Actually the max impact is 75%, but this only applies to deck joints.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though it is a bit confusing since I am accustomed to working with the metric system (e.g. *t = tonne = 1000 kg*). For those who are unfamiliar with kip: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kip_(unit)

Comment: A 36-50 tonnes truck seems relatively small for the heaviest truck. In the comments to my post, people cited trucks carrying payloads well over 100 tonnes.

Comment: @Triceratops of course such trucks exist and carry loads over the road all the time. That's why we have "load rating" procedures for existing roads and bridges, to determine what they can actually carry. And that's also why localities require weighing of trucks, etc. But something like 36 to 45 tons (short tons; 32.5 to 41 tonnes) is all the AASHTO code- which is the model engineering code for the various state codes- requires for bridge and road design in the US. Any higher load is likely going to require a special consideration, and not going to be automatically assumed to be OK.

Comment: So, a truck in the US needs special permission to carry over 45 tonnes? I know that in my country (non-US) HET semi-trailers that carry heavy bulldozers (> 50 t) and full-trailer dump trucks are quite common.

Comment: @Triceratops Mostly correct, but this limit varies by state. [Here](https://ops.fhwa.dot.gov/freight/policy/rpt_congress/truck_sw_laws/index.htm) is a reference for the federal regulation as of 2012, and the axle limits there are even lower than what I have given above (gross vehicle weight is slightly higher). But again, it is going to be different in every state; federal regulation isn't the end of the discussion.

Comment: @Triceratops But don't misunderstand: just because higher weights require a "special permission" doesn't mean they are uncommon. They are VERY common. Getting permission isn't that difficult; there are processes in place for it, and again, that process will differ by state. But nevertheless, the weight limit that requires no special permission is going be something like the 36 to 45 (short) ton range (for a 3 axle truck, at least).